Tailwind CSS intellisense not initializing
Suddenly, My Tailwind CSS Intellisense is not working(initializing).
I've seen plenty of other questions, And Tried almost everything.
Here is my additions in settings.json
  "files.associations": {
    "globals.css": "tailwindcss"
  },
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": { "plaintext": "javascript" },

Here is the output of my tailwind css intellisense:
Locating server…
Booting server...
Setting up server…
Listening for messages…
Searching for Tailwind CSS projects in the workspace's folders.
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
[Global] Creating projects: [{"folder":"C:\\Users\\Anay\\documents\\folder","config":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts","selectors":[{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts","priority":0},{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/**","priority":3}],"user":false,"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}},{"folder":"C:\\Users\\Anay\\documents\\folder","config":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts","selectors":[{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts","priority":0},{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/**","priority":3}],"user":false,"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}]
[Global] Preparing projects...
[Global] Adding watch patterns: C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder, C:/Users/Anay/Documents, C:/Users/Anay, C:/Users, C:/, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder, C:/Users/Anay/Documents, C:/Users/Anay, C:/Users, C:/
[Global] Adding watch patterns: C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main
[Global] Initializing projects...
[Global] Initialized 0 projects
Booting server...
Setting up server…
Listening for messages…
Searching for Tailwind CSS projects in the workspace's folders.
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
{"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}
[Global] Creating projects: [{"folder":"C:\\Users\\Anay\\documents\\folder","config":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts","selectors":[{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts","priority":0},{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/**","priority":3}],"user":false,"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.4","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}},{"folder":"C:\\Users\\Anay\\documents\\folder","config":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts","selectors":[{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts","priority":0},{"pattern":"C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/**","priority":3}],"user":false,"tailwind":{"version":"3.4.3","features":["layer:base","separator:root","content-list","jit","css-at-config","relative-content-paths","transpiled-configs"],"isDefaultVersion":false}}]
[Global] Preparing projects...
[Global] Adding watch patterns: C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder, C:/Users/Anay/Documents, C:/Users/Anay, C:/Users, C:/, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/cms, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder, C:/Users/Anay/Documents, C:/Users/Anay, C:/Users, C:/
[Global] Adding watch patterns: C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main/tailwind.config.ts, C:/Users/Anay/Documents/folder/main
[Global] Initializing projects...
[Global] Initialized 0 projects

I've also seen this question, My TailWind CSS Intellisense plugin just isn't working on my VSCode
I also tried most of the solutions in it, but none seemed to work.

Upon checking, it was known issue, and is being tracked here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/988
